# Getting WooCommerce product attributes within Twig/Timber and calling PHP methods

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, twig, timber

I'm building a WooCommerce site whilst utilising the Twig templating system along with the Timber WordPress plugin and following along with [this guide](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/docs/guides/woocommerce.md#tease-product) for the tease template.

However, looking at WooCommerce's own default `templates/content-product.php` they have this at the very top:

```
// Ensure visibility.
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}
```

So I'm thinking that we should be doing the same check in the template file? However I am unsure how to check this value in Twig.

I have tried `dump(post.is_visible())` but every one returns `(bool) false`.

I additionally have no idea where `showthumb` is coming from and couldn't find much information or docs about this particular setting/attribute.

**Edit:** Here is my controller: *(my-theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php)*

```
$context            = Timber::get_context();
$context['shop-sidebar'] = Timber::get_widgets( 'shop-sidebar' );

$posts = Timber::get_posts();
$context['products'] = $posts;

if ( is_product_category() ) {
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
    $context['category'] = get_term( $term_id, 'product_cat' );
    $context['title'] = single_term_title( '', false );
}

Timber::render( 'views/woo/archive.twig', $context );
```

Here is my *archive.twig* file:

```
{% extends 'archive.twig' %} {# Base Archive File #}

{% block before_article %}
    {% do action('woocommerce_before_main_content') %}
{% endblock %}

{% block below_h1 %}
    {% do action('woocommerce_archive_description') %}
{% endblock %}

{% block primary_block %}

    {% if products|length > 0 %}

        <div class="before-products">
            {% do action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop') %}
        </div>

        <div class="products-wrap">
            <div class="products row flex">
                {% for post in products %}
                    <div class="product col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        {% do action('woocommerce_shop_loop') %}
                        {% include ["woo/partials/tease-product.twig"] %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="after-products">
            {% do action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop') %}
        </div>

    {% else %}

        <div class="no-products">
            {% do action('woocommerce_no_products_found') %}
        </div>

    {% endif %}

{% endblock  %}

{% block after_article %}
    {% do action('woocommerce_after_main_content') %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my *tease-product.twig* file:

```
<article {{ fn('post_class', ['entry'] ) }}>

    {{ fn('timber_set_product', post) }}

    <div class="media">

        <div class="media-figure {% if not post.thumbnail %}placeholder{% endif %}">
            <a href="{{ post.link }}">
                {% if post.thumbnail %}
                    <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src|resize(600)|e('esc_url') }}" class="img-responsive" />
                {% else %}
                    <span class="thumb-placeholder"><i class="icon-camera"></i></span>
                {% endif %}
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="media-content">

            {% do action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item') %}
            {% do action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title') %}

            {% if post.title %}
                <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
            {% else %}
                <h3 class="entry-title"><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ fn('the_title') }}</a></h3>
            {% endif %}

            {% do action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' ) %}
            {% do action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ) %}

        </div>

    </div>

</article>
```

How can I retrieve the correct value of the `is_visible` method?

Comment: `showThumb` is a variable passed from the controller to the view. You are calling `product.is_visible()` correctly. Are you sure you are using the correct `product`?

Comment: I am using basically the same controller as in their example further up the page, but I am not using the single `woocommerce.php` file, instead I am doing it the other _per template_ way - I will update my question with the controller. Only reason I was asking about `showThumb` is they were using it in their view without setting it in their controller, so I was curious if it was supposed to come from somewhere else.

Comment: Could be a global `twig` variable set in the config. Not familiar with `woocommerce` myself. But as I said in my comment `product.is_visble()` should suffice to use it inside twig

Answer (score 0):

I reckon OP has solved the problem by now. But, for future reference...

You should be able to do `{{ post.is_visible }}` to output the value.

Similarly, both `if` statements below work for me.

`{% if (product.is_visible) %}`
`{% if (product.is_visible()) %}`

Now, I am fairly new to WooCommerce and Timber, and  I don't know much about `is_visible`, so I apologize if I am wrong here. But, I know I Am able to use [WC_Product member functions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) in twig templates like {{ variable.*function_name* }}, ie. `{{ product.get_title }}` or `{{ product.get_price }}`, so I expect `is_visible` to be no different.